# Name resolution when a structure declaration is hidden by a variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, dependent-name, name-hiding

Let's consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    struct B 
    {
        int b = 10;
    };
    int B = 20;
};

template <class T>
struct C
{
    void f() const
    {
        typename /*struct*/ T::B b;
        int x = b.b;
        std::cout << "x == " << x << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<A>().f();
}
```

As it is seen the declaration of the member `struct B` in the structure `A` is hidden by the declaration of the data member `B` having the type `int`.

So in the function definition of the template structure declaration

```
typename /*struct*/ T::B b;
```

the depended name `T::B` should not be found.

However the compiler `gcc 8.3` compiles the program successfully and the program outputs

```
x == 10
```

On the other hand, the compiler **Visual C++ 2019** is not going to compile the program and issues a syntax error.

So is it a bug of the compiler **gcc 8.3**?

The second problem is that it would be natural if such a construction (with uncommented keyword struct) with an elaborated type specifier would be allowed.

```
typename struct T::B b;
```

However the both compilers consider the construction as incorrect.

Is it indeed incorrect?

Comment: It is incorrect. A correct usage of an elaborate type specifier would be `struct T::B b;` - no `typename`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But according to the C++ 17 Standard "2 A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is assumed
not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified by the
keyword typename." That is the keyword typename is required.

Comment: Also according to the C++17 standard *"A qualified name used as the name in a class-or-decltype or an elaborated-type-specifier is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the typename keyword. In a nested-name-specifier that immediately contains a nested-name-specifier that depends on a template parameter, the identifier or simple-template-id is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the typename keyword. [ Note: The typename keyword is not permitted by the syntax of these constructs.  — end note ]*"

Comment: Hence not only not required, but also disallowed https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#5

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica A good reference. I did not yet read this paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a bug of the compiler gcc 8.3. Because the standard rule that `typename  T::B` shall be resolved to variable rather than `struct B`, these rules are listed in the following:

> A class name or enumeration name can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member, function, or enumerator declared **in the same scope**. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is visible.

The above rule says that the name of `struct B` was hidden by the name of declaration `int B = 20;`

> When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation ([temp.dep.type]) and its nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword typename, forming a typename-specifier. If the qualified-id in a typename-specifier does not denote a type or a class template, the program is ill-formed.

> The **usual qualified name lookup** is used to find the qualified-id even in the presence of typename.

The above rule says that the keyword `typename` does not affect the result of `qualified name lookup`, In other words, the keyword `typename` does not require that the name lookup procedure only finds types.

So, in the scope of `A`, the declarations of `int B = 20;` and `struct B`  are all found, and then the variable hides `class name`. So, according to rule **If the qualified-id in a typename-specifier does not denote a type or a class template, the program is ill-formed**, the program should be ill-formed. Hence, **GCC 8.3** is wrong.

In addition, not only `GCC 8.3` but also the higher versions are all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

from my vision : in **f( )** function you need to declare **struct**  to avoid this problem

```
template <class T> struct C {
        void f() const {
            // just normal struct
            struct T::B structB;
            int x = structB.b;
    
            std::cout << "x == " << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and in **main** call **f( )** normally like that :

```
C<A> j; 
// call
j.f();
```

i hope all of that worthed :)